# Convert from table to matrix format with Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, database, pivot-table, power-query

I would like to convert this data from table to matrix format where the names in the dest column become columns and the number values corresponds to the total but the origin column stands still

```
origin    dest  total

Aadami  Haaslava    3
Aadami  Ignase      3
Aadami  Päkste     20
Aadami  Roiu        1
Aadami  Soinaste    1
Aadami  Tartu      500
Aadami  Uniküla     2
Aakaru  Tartu       8
Aakre   Elva       129
Aakre   Kõduküla   722
Aakre   Palupera    4
Aakre   Pedaste     1
Aakre   Raigaste    1
Aakre   Rebaste     3
```

Expected output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvKvG.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you copy "dest" to another column and then use Columns to Rows on the new column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all data, click insert and select pivot table. Follow the prompts.

On the config screen drag *dest* to column labels, *origin* to row labels, and *total* to values.

Comment: Works, thanks a lot :)